# Video doesn't fit properly

Tags: android, android-videoview

Hi I have a VideoView in my app, provided the layout width and height as fill parent. But still my video is displayed only in half the portion of the videoView. So I tried providing the width and height in dip. But still the video displays in the same manner. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: it's hard to help without seeing your code / layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by creating an own VideoView class extending VideoView, then pass in the width and height from

```
new VideoPlayer(this, getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
```

And this is the VideoPlayer class

```
public class VideoPlayer extends VideoView {

private int width;
private int height;

public VideoPlayer(Context context, int width, int height) {
    super(context);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public VideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
     setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
}
```

I then added the VideoPlayer view by code to the layout using ViewGroup.addView(VideoPlayer)